# google map- zoom to my location

Tags: android, google-maps

I always struggle a lot with google maps library on Android. My code to zoom to location is really simple:

```
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
    if (location != null)
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 14));
```

For some reason, the location is usually null so it doesn't zoom it however, I can see the "blue spot" on the map.

Answer (score 0):

> "blue spot" on the map

is `MyLocation` marker. You can hide it via [`setMyLocationEnabled()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setMyLocationEnabled(boolean)) call:

```
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
if (location != null) {
    // show "blue spot"
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 14));
} else {
    // hide "blue spot"
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
}
```

and don't forget about permission check.

Comment: I know that it is My Location. My problem is that I can see it on the map, but still, sometimes the location variable is null so it doesn't call animateCamera. I want to know, why does it happen?